# Изменение высоты моего UserControl

Tags: c#, binding

Есть UserControl, вставляю его в этом окне, делаю биндинг этого UserControl к высоте окна(+ пропускаю через фильтр), ожидал, что растянется весь, но выходит только так
[image]

Ратягивает область, но не UserControl
Как добиться желаемого эффекта?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение найдено, вопрос не удаляю, так как деталь заслуживает внимания.
Мой контрол состоит из <Border> и внутри другие элементы.
Что было и что стало.  
<UserControl Height="auto" Width="auto"> и <Border Height="200" Width="300">

и стало 
 <UserControl Height="200" Width="300"> и <Border Height="auto" Width="auto">